# Why is Sequelize only returning one object using findAll()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

My goal is to be able to find all products by their brand name and model name. However, Sequelize is only returning one record out of many other similar records. If it does return more than one record, other records with identical attributes as the first record found will be `null`. For example, the first record in the array will have the attribute `name: iPhone`, the second record which has the exact same attribute will be shown as `name: null` when it should be `name: iPhone`.

In my database, I have the following tables:

`Products`, `Brands`, `Models`, and `Suppliers`. The `Products` table contains foreign keys such as `brand_id`, `model_id`, etc.. `Brands`, `Models`, and `Suppliers` have the attribute: `id`.

I have set the relationship up as the following:

```
Products.hasOne(Brands, { foreignKey: 'id' });
Products.hasOne(Models, { foreignKey: 'id' });
Products.hasOne(Suppliers, { foreignKey: 'id' });

Brands.belongsTo(Products);
Models.belongsTo(Products);
Suppliers.belongsTo(Products);
```

In my search function, I attempt to find all products by brand and model name that match my query.

```
const getSearch = (req, res) => {
  const { query: { query } } = req;

  Products.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('Brand.name'), ' ', Sequelize.col('Model.name')), {
      [Op.substring]: query
    }),
    include: [
      { model: Brands, attributes: ['name'] },
      { model: Models, attributes: ['name'] },
      { model: Suppliers, attributes: ['name'] },
    ],
    attributes: ['id', 'price']
  })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => (console.log(err)));
};
```

In my database, I have two product rows with the exact same data but different ids. When calling `getSearch` I expect to see two objects in the array as they have the same brand name and model name. Instead I see one.

Here's what my models look like:

Products

```
class Products extends Model {
  static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return super.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        url_id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: true
        },
        brand_id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: true
        },
        model_id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: true
        },
        supplier_id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: true
        },
        image: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: true
        },
        description: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: true
        },
        price: {
          type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
          allowNull: true
        }
      },
      {
        modelName: 'Products',
        timestamps: false,
        sequelize
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Models

```
class Models extends Model {
  static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return super.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: true
        },
        colour_id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: true
        },
        storage_capacity_id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: true
        }
      },
      {
        modelName: 'Models',
        timestamps: false,
        sequelize
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Brands

```
class Brands extends Model {
  static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return super.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: true
        }
      },
      {
        modelName: 'Brands',
        timestamps: false,
        sequelize
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Suppliers

```
class Suppliers extends Model {
  static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return super.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: true
        }
      },
      {
        modelName: 'Suppliers',
        timestamps: false,
        sequelize
      }
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in associations. Just change hasOne to hasMany and you are done.

Comment: All associations should be flipped. Brands/Models/Suppliers may have many Products. One product belongsTo one Brand.